# A GRE - Probability Question

Tags: probability, gre-exam

In a probability experiment, G and H are independent events. The probability that G will occur is r, and the probability that H will occur is s, where both r and s are greater than 0.

Quantity A
The probability that either G will occur or H will occur, but not both.

Quantity B
r+s-rs

A) Quantity A is greater.
B) Quantity B is greater.
C) The two quantities are equal.
D) The relationship cannot be determined from the information given.

The answer is B. How?

Comment: The answer is actually B...

Comment: Yeah sorry the answer is B.

Comment: Look at my answer. Do you understand why?

Comment: No :(
I understand that P(G OR H) = P(G) + P(H) - P(G AND H). Why is there one more P(G AND H) subracted which is already negated?

Comment: Note the **but not both** at the end of the description of $A$. We have $A = P(G \Delta H) = P(G \cup H) - P(G\cap H)$

Comment: Oh my. I think I understand when i imagine it as a venn diagram.
I imagined 2 circles G and H which has some union.
Now P(G and H) is the area of G and H and the common area removed.
But when they say "but not both", they mean the region which is exactly G and exactly H and not the union region. So thats why we remove the comman region again. Thanks alex. I just realized that am lacking basics.

Comment: The 'or' used in your probability statement P(G or H) means "G or H or both" in common language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$A = \underbrace{P(G \cup H)}_{\text{either $G$ or $H$}} - \underbrace{P(G\cap H)}_{\text{but not both}} = P(G) + P(H) - P(G\cap H) - P(G\cap H) = r + s - 2rs$$
By [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).
$$B = r + s - rs = P(G) + P(H) - P(G\cap H) = P(G\cup H)$$
Since
$$A = r + s - 2rs < r+s-rs = B$$
We have that B) is the correct answer. $\Box$

Comment: Yeah sorry the answer is B

Answer (score 1):

As another way of looking at it:

Probability that G occurs but not H is $r(1-s)$

and Probability that H occurs but not G is $s(1-r)$.

Adding gives $r+s-2rs$ which is less than $r+s-rs$.